# systax error in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In php-myadmin . while runnig this query I am getting it like ..Import has been successfully finished, 0 queries executed. (getpaywall.com_2013-06-16.sql)

But its not giving me that the procedures . please solve this issue:

```
DELIMITER $;
CREATE PROCEDURE `ISSUE_REFUND`(IN buyer_user_id INT, IN order_id INT, IN refund_amount DECIMAL(5,2), IN refund_feedback TEXT)
BEGIN
    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT customer_user_id,paid_amount,status INTO @userid,@paidamount,@orderstatus FROM orders WHERE id=order_id;
    IF @orderstatus='failed' OR @orderstatus='refunded' OR @orderstatus='partial_refunded' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Order already refunded or failed!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1004;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        IF @userid=buyer_user_id THEN
            IF refund_amount <= @paidamount THEN
                IF refund_amount=@paidamount THEN
                    SET @type1='refunded';
                ELSE
                    SET @type1='partial_refunded';
                END IF;
                UPDATE orders SET status=@type1,refunded_comment=refund_feedback,refunded_amount=refund_amount WHERE id=order_id;
                COMMIT;
            ELSE
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Refund amount cannot be greater than paidamount!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1005;
                ROLLBACK;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Customer ID in orders does not match with given buyer_user_id!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1003;
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;$
DELIMITER ;$
```

and when i run it through terminal by using

> mysql -u root -p paywall < getpaywall.com_2013-06-16.sql

i had an error which says

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT customer_user_id,paid_' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you export a procedure then you will find username of the DB from where you have exported change that username.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;.... what does this mean  and i didnt get it
    SELECT customer_user_id,paid_' at line 3